# Using GETDATE() in a variable returns 0 rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query that declares and sets a datetime variable at the very beginning:

```
declare @_NextAppt as datetime
set @_NextAppt = dateadd(dd,3,getdate())
```

when I check it and execute a select @_NextAppt it returns three days from today which is what I want.

The problem occurs in my next select statement when I use

```
where table.apptdate = @_NextAppt
```

The query returns no rows.

Here's the sample query:

```
select distinct PatID, StaffID  
from dbo.Appointments    
where PatID is not null and ApptDate = @_NextAppt
```

I can get everything to work if I replace getdate() with an exact date like '11/09/2016'. But that doesn't work long term for my report.

What am I missing?  I'm relatively new to SQL and self taught so I'm sure there is some SQL quirk that I don't know about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `GETDATE()` returns a `DATETIME`. So the `WHERE` condition checks if any of the values in that column is equal to that exact date and time (+3 days).

You need to strip the time part, either by casting or by using a `date` variable:

```
declare @_NextAppt as datetime ;        -- use same type as the column

set @_NextAppt = dateadd(day, 3, cast(getdate() as date)) ;
      -- strips the time from getdate(),
      -- adds 3 days and
      -- does an implicit conversion to the variable's type (datetime)
```

We also don't know the type of the column. It would be good to use inclusive-exclusive conditions when comparing datetime values. The query below will work independent of whether your column is `DATE` or `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2`:

```
select distinct PatID, StaffID  
from dbo.Appointments    
where PatID is not null 
  and ApptDate >= @_NextAppt
  and ApptDate  < dateadd(day, 1, @_NextAppt) ;
```

If the column is `DATE`, you could of course use an equality condition:

```
---
where PatID is not null 
  and ApptDate = @_NextAppt ;
```

Necessary links to blog posts about good (and bad) practices with dates (note how I replaced the shorthand `dd` to the full `day` datepart when using the `DATEADD()` function above):

- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I appreciate it and will read the Bad Habits articles.